# Why does overflow happen when translating an element if the box model isn't affected?

Tags: css, css-transforms

Applying transforms to an element, to me, has always meant that the box model isn't moving and that the element is just moving visually.

I was wondering how this works with regards to overflow. If the element's box model hasn't been moved then how does the browser know that the element is breaking out of its parent's box?

```css
.outer {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translateY(110%);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer'>
  <div class='inner'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that transforms do not affect box layout, however [the spec makes an exception for overflow](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-rendering):

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model, the transform property does not affect the flow of the content surrounding the transformed element. However, the extent of the overflow area takes into account transformed elements. This behavior is similar to what happens when elements are offset via relative positioning. Therefore, if the value of the ‘overflow’ property is ‘scroll’ or ‘auto’, scrollbars will appear as needed to see content that is transformed outside the visible area.